# AJAX/Javascript Get Submitted Form Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

In javascript I am creating multiple forms and inputting into html us ajax/js like this:

```
function addProduct(product) {
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<div>'
                    html += '<form id="product-form">';
                    html += '<div class="city">'+product['product_name']+'</div>'
                    html += '<div class="state">'+product['product_price']+'</div>'
                    html += '<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="'+product['product_id']+'" id="product_id" >'
                    html += '<a href="#" class="whiteButton submit" id="view-product-button" >View</a>'
                    html += '</form>'
                    html += '</div>'
                    var insert = $(html);
                    $('#main').append(html);
                }
```

Multiples of these forms are created with different product_ids. The problem I am running into is getting the values of just that form. I am able to correctly identify the form that was submitted but I am not sure out to the the product_id from the input. So far I have this:

```
$('#main').on('submit', '#product-form', function() {

                    var product_id = $('?????').val()

                });
```

How can I get the product id and other related data from the form that was submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class instead of id for forms and use submit button instead of "a tag", then make your submit function like this

```
$('.form_class').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formUrl=form.attr('action');
    var product_id = $('#product_id', form).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: formUrl,
        data: product_id, // or use form.serialize();
        success: function(data){
            // code goes here;
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            // code goes here;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a context to the jQuery `$()` function:

```
var product_id = $('input[name=product_id]', this).val();
```

The `'input...'` selector will apply only within the context of the second parameter, in this case `this`, where `this` will be set by jQuery to be the current form element within the the `submit` handler.

Alternatively you can select the current form first and then `.find()` elements within it:

```
var product_id = $(this).find('input[name=product_id]').val();
```

Note that I'm selecting the input by name because although you've given that element an `id` attribute it is not valid to assign the same `id` to multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('.city').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
$('#main').on('submit', '#product-form', function() {
    var product_id = $(this).children('input[name=product_id]').val();
});
```

But I can see a problem with your function. In fact, calling `addProduct(...)` multiple times will end up invalidating your DOM, since you will have more elements with the same id (`product-form`, `product_id` and `view-product-button`). Better review the whole idea behind it...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must not create multiple elements with the same id. Use class.
There is a lot of ids in your javascript, but for the Form it'll be :
`html += '<form class="product-form">';` for the form declaration and `$('#main').on('submit', '.product-form', function() {` to catch the event.

Then, when you catch an event, `this` will refer to the current event target. You can retrieve the value of the product by using : $('input[name=product_id]', this)[0].value